# Calculating covariance with random variables $W_t iid N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Tags: probability

Suppose that $x_t=w_tw_{t-1}$ where $w_t~ N(0, \sigma^2)$ (iid white noise). Calculate 
$$Cov(x_t,x_t)=var(x_t)=E(w_t^2*w_{t-1}^2)-((E(w_t)E(w_{t-1}))^2=E(w_t^2*w_{t-1}^2)-E(w_t)^2E(w_{t-1})^2=\sigma^4$$.

Would this be correct?

Comment: There is an error in the second line.

Comment: I fixed it. I had a sign error and exponent misplacement. Is it fine now?

Comment: That looks correct.  Interestingly the expected value of $x_t^4$ is not $\sigma^4$, because $x_t^2$ is not independent from itself (obviously), whereas here, $x_t^2$ is independent from $x_{t-1}^2$ ....

Comment: I took the liberty of writing up an answer that details some of the steps and justifications.  Let me know how I can improve this - I just want to give the best answer I can.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is much more complete than mines.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The covariance can be expressed in terms of expectations as

$$\text{Cov} (x,y) = \text{E}(xy)-\text{E}(x) \text{E}(y)$$

If $x=y$, then

$$\text{Cov} (x,x) = \text{E}(x^2)-\left(\text{E}(x)\right)^2$$

whereupon substituting $x=w_tw_{t-1}$ reveals that

$$\text{Cov} (x,x) = \text{E}(w_t^2w_{t-1}^2)-\left(\text{E}(w_tw_{t-1})\right)^2= \text{E}(w_t^2w_{t-1}^2)-\left(\text{E}(w_t)\text{E}(w_{t-1}))\right)^2$$

where the last step relies on the independence of $w_t$ and $w_{t-1}$.

But since $\text{E}(w_t)=\text{E}(w_{t-1})=0$ by assumption, we have

$$\text{Cov} (x,x) = \text{E}(w_t^2w_{t-1}^2)$$

Now, if $x$ and $y$ are independent, then it is easy to show that $x^2$ and $y^2$ are independent.  Thus,

$$\begin{align}
\text{Cov} (x,x) &= \text{E}(w_t^2w_{t-1}^2)\\
&=\text{E}(w_t^2)\text{E}(w_{t-1}^2)\\
&=\sigma^2 \times \sigma^2\\
&=\sigma^4
\end{align}$$